Operator precedence of `EXISTS`
In Postgres, does the EXISTS operator have the highest precedence of all? For example:
SELECT 1 + EXISTS (SELECT 1)::int;

It seems to be missing from the manual page. Though the highest one is ::, meaning EXISTS would be higher?
In other words, it evaluates it like this:
select (exists (select 1))::int;

And not like this, which, if you try, will error:
select exists ((select 1)::int);

Meaning that the EXISTS operator has higher precedence than the CAST operator. Is this correct?

Note: adding a bounty and changing this from SQL to any RDBMS that supports EXISTS (which I believe is all mainstream?)

Your query is casting TRUE, the result from EXISTS to an integer, to number 1. See also SELECT 1 + EXISTS (SELECT 1 WHERE 1=2)::int; Better use CAST() when you want to cast.

@FrankHeikens see the updated question, I just mean the order of operations.

Oracle in facts does have a table of precedence for SQL ... not explicitly stated, but this probably follows the ANSI standard, which Postgres also closely follows.

I took the liberty to update your link with a link to the current manual. Note that things changed a bit since the ancient version 7.2, and . is now the number 1. You may want to adapt your text.

EXISTS is a predicate. (Other predicates are comparison predicate, between, like, in, etc.)

The elephant in the room: EXISTS is not an operator in Postgres, technically speaking.
It's a syntax element. The manual lists it in the chapter "Subquery Expressions". Operator precedence does not apply. EXISTS "binds" before any operator. The Postgres source code uses the term "SubLink" for this kind of plan node.
Accordingly, you'll also find no corresponding entry in pg_operator.
Also accordingly, in your example, :: ranking number 2 in operator precedence doesn't make the cut. Your test isn't ideal, though. Either precedence would result in integer 1:
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1)::int;
This is unambiguous:
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 'foo')::int;

Would error out, if ::int took precedence - like this does:
--  invalid input syntax for type integer: "foo"
SELECT        (SELECT 'foo')::int;

In case you still want more proof: even the number 1 in the operator precedence ranking, the column separator (.), can't overcome the gravitational pull of EXISTS:
CREATE  TABLE t (id int);

SELECT        (SELECT t FROM t LIMIT 1).id;  -- valid
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT t FROM t LIMIT 1).id;  -- invalid!

fiddle
The second SELECT would try to append .id to the boolean value true, which is a syntax error.

is the "Operator" distinction a semantic difference that differs from DB to DB? For example in BigQuery they call it the "Exists Operator": https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#exists_operator. Maybe it just parses the query as the tokens (simplified): [ <"SELECT">, <"1">, <existsSubquery>, <castOp>] and so the "operator precedence" doesn't even matter in this case because the existsSubquery includes the sub-select: might that be it?

I am speaking of Postgres terminology. It's conceivable to see EXISTS as "operator", it's just not in the narrower sense in Postgres. Other RDBMS may draw the lines differently. And sure, EXISTS not being an operator, it's parsed differently. That's the point. Your idea is pretty close to the actual implementation. The Postgres source code speaks of a "SubLink" and has more details.

I think I figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the direction here. I added my own answer that uses Antlr as a helper to illustrate, but it's a general grammar issue rather than operator/element precedence.

This is not a matter of operator precedence but of how a grammar is parsed, in this case SQL. Let's step back a bit and take a basic arithmetic example for this:
3+3*2

If we ignore operator precedence, there are two valid ways to parse this statement:
(3+3)  * 2     = 12

And:
3 +    (3*2)   = 9

Both of these are valid parses. Operator precedence is used when there are multiple valid parses to resolve ambiguity. Notice, however, that the following is not a valid parse:
(3+3*)      2  = /error/

So before we bring in operator precedence to resolve ambiguities, we must first have a validly parsed expression.

Now we'll return back to the question at hand. We will modify it slightly as well so that the literal used is not castable to an INT:
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT DATE '2014-01-01')::INT

In the question, it was assumed that there may be two possible ways to validly parse this statement:
SELECT (EXISTS <subselect>)     ::INT

And:
SELECT EXISTS        (<subselect>::INT)

But in fact, the latter parse is invalid, the <subselect>::INT will return an INT (or runtime error), not a sub-select, and so (substituting a placeholder value of 1 to make it more clear) SELECT EXISTS 1 is not a valid statement.
In other words, you only have one valid parse, and so operator precedence is totally irrelevant.
Here is an example Antlr program that demonstrates this (you can copy-paste it into this site to view, though it doesn't allow you to save-and-share the grammar like most pastebin sites do):
// SELECT NOT (SELECT 55)::VARCHAR
// SELECT EXISTS (SELECT DATE '2014-01-01')::INT

grammar ExprParser;

program: 
    select EOF
    ;

select: 
    SELECT expr
    ;

subselect: 
    OPEN_PAREN select CLOSE_PAREN
    ;

expr:
    LITERAL            # LiteralExpr
  | subselect          # SubselectExpr
  | EXISTS subselect   # ExistsExpr
  | NOT expr           # LogicalExpr 
  | expr CAST TYPE     # CastExpr
    ;

SELECT : 'SELECT' ;
EXISTS : 'EXISTS' ;
LITERAL: 'DATE \'2014-01-01\'' | '55';
CAST: '::';
OPEN_PAREN: '(';
CLOSE_PAREN: ')';
TYPE: 'INT'|'BOOL'|'DATE';
NOT: 'NOT';

WS: [ \t\n\r\f]+ -> skip ;

Let's now take a different query that does show operator precedence in action:
SELECT NOT (SELECT 55)::VARCHAR;

Here it can be parsed in two ways:
SELECT NOT   ((SELECT 55)::VARCHAR)           --> NOT "55" --> Error

And:
SELECT (NOT (SELECT 55))       ::VARCHAR;     --> false::varchar --> "false"

Here the first approach is used since the :: operator has higher precedence than NOT. In this way, ironically, the EXISTS is applied before the cast operation, though the NOT is applied after the cast operation. The EXISTS is applied first because there is only one possible grammatical parse, whereas with the NOT there are two possible parses, and so we use operator precedence to resolve ambiguity.
You can view both example queries for the grammar here.
And both parse trees in Antlr if useful:


